# Apache htaccess rewrite (Pretty URLs)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a sneaking suspicion this is not possible, but figured I would ask regardless.

Is it at all possible to take a URL passed to a server in the form of:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?Action=Controller/Action&one=1&two=2&three=3
```

And rewrite it to appear as:

```
http://domain.com/Controller/Action/1/2/3
```

I am trying to clean up an borderline ancient project to support "Pretty URLs" and I would really like to make the URLs display a bit nicer. I know I could setup a 301 header redirect to the new URL, but I would prefer to avoid that overhead if at all possible.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get

```
http://domain.com/index.php?Action=Controller/Action&one=1&two=2&three=3
```

To appear as

```
http://domain.com/Controller/Action/1/2/3
```

You will need to use `%{QUERY_STRING}` to capture the query string data. Your .htaccess file will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Action=Controller/Action&one=(\d+)&two=(\d+)&three=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^.+ /Controller/Action/%1/%2/%3 [R=301,L]
```

This will set up a permanent redirect to the new page. You can play around and test .htaccess rewrite rules here: [htaccess.madewithlove.be](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?Action=$1/$2&one=$3&two=$4&three=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Interesting I will have to give this a shot. As a side note, the additional GET params were just as an example, is there any way to filter any number of them or optionally just leave them untouched?

EG:
?Action=Controller/Action&one=1&two=2&three=3
Turns into:
Controller/Action&one=1&two=2&three=3

Thanks!